# webElement.submit() does not work in selenium 3.14.0 and appium client 6.1.0

Tags: selenium, appium-android

I have upgraded selenium with selenium3.14.0 and appium-client 6.0.1 but webElement.submit does not work.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error? did it work before the upgrade?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to tap on the element then it's suggested that you use AndroidTouchAction to tap on the element.

**Also you need to use latest Appium Java client 6.1.0.**